# JS how to get variable that invoked function?

Tags: javascript, function

i would like to get the variable that invoke a function, i'v searched but i didn't find..

To be clearer,

```
var time = 60

function timer() {
    variableName--
    console.log(variableName)
    return variableName
}

setInterval(() => {
    time = timer()
}, 1000)
```

So, i would like to know variableName, in fact variableName is time so i can do

```
time = timer(time)
```

But, it's not very.. i don't know, there is obviously a way to get variable assigned to a function, (i don't know how to say that but i hope you understood me)

So, i want my code to be the more clearest and reusable as posible,
In fact, i'm programing a socket timer,

It's like:

```
socket.on('timerStart', () => {
    TIMER = timer()
    console.log(TIMER)
}

function timer() {
    if(variableThatInvoked > 0) {
        variableThatInvoked--
        return variableThatInvoked
    }
}
```

So, how to get variableThatInvoked ?

Comment: timer is called asynchronously, it's return value is not returned to `time`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var time = function timer() {
    console.log("time called");
}
```

Below is your async function which uses `setTimeout`

```
function async(your_function, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        your_function();
        if (callback) {callback();}
    }, 0);
}


async(time, function() {console.log(time);});
```

Comment: Well, the heck is that i wan't to make my code the more clearer and reusable, and, in your enxemple, i need to declare my function, i think i haven't explain enought my problem

Comment: The above code is more resusable, as you are not making your timer function clean and leaving it to interface async to do the job with a additional callback to get what ever you want...

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to do something like

```js
var time = 60

function timer(variableName) {
    variableName--
    console.log(variableName)
    return variableName
}

setInterval(() => {
    time = timer(time)
}, 1000)
```

You can exactly see what you are passing.

And in `time = timer()` for the function call there's no reference to `time` at any point

Comment: Yep i've do like in your exemple but i think its dumb to specify 'time' a second time

Comment: You could use something like `curry` but you would need to use objects so it work properly with your example. Imo passing `time` is ok, it's clean and you can immediately see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Well, thank you guys, i'v seen that it's not posible, so i'v turned it into class logic

So, for thoses who were like me, there is the Timer class:

```
            class Timer {
                constructor(left, rate, func, callback) {
                    this.left = left
                    this.rate = rate
                    this.func = func
                    this.cb = callback
                }

                start() {
                    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                        this.func()
                        this.left--
                        if(this.left < 0) {clearInterval(this.interval); this.cb()}   
                    }, 1000 / this.rate)
                }
            }
```

And so, when a receive a server socket who say 'hey, let's begin the timer !':

```
            socket.on('startTimer', (servLeft) => {
                timer = new Timer(servLeft, 2, () => {
                    console.log(timer.left)
                    }, () => {console.log('timer ended!')})

                timer.start()
            })
```

Logical rendering:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Timer</title>
        <script>
            class Timer {
                constructor(left, rate, func, callback) {
                    this.left = left
                    this.rate = rate
                    this.func = func
                    this.cb = callback
                }

                start() {
                    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                        this.func()
                        this.left--
                        if(this.left < 0) {clearInterval(this.interval); this.cb()}   
                    }, 1000 / this.rate)
                }
            }


            timer = new Timer(20, 1, () => {console.log(timer.left)}, () => {console.log('Timer ended!')})
            timer.start()
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <hi>Simple timer</hi>
    </body>
</html>
```